# Fiddler: The connection to 'localhost' failed. with owin selfhost

Tags: asp.net-web-api, owin

I have the following simple console app hosting a webapi using Owin SelfHost. The response from the console itself works but if trying from fiddler i just get a connection to localhost failed. (same with a browser).

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string baseAddress = "http://localhost:34300/";
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("da-dk");
            // Start OWIN host 
            using (WebApp.Start<Startup>(url: baseAddress))
            {
                // Create HttpCient and make a request to api/values 
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

                var response = client.GetAsync(baseAddress + "api/GpsPositions").Result;

                Console.WriteLine(response);
                Console.WriteLine(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
                Console.WriteLine("Listening on " + baseAddress);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        } 
    }
```

Am i missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have `Console.ReadLine();` inside the using block. Without that web app will be disposed. Since you are making the call using `HttpClient` within the using block before the web app is disposed it works.